# Acrobat form data - export as XML - add button

Tags: javascript, xml, forms, button, acrobat

Please help - trying to create button on PDF page - need to export to XML not FDF

exportAsXML(); - nothing happens ...

exportAsFDF(); - exports OK but cannot import to my Excel XML map/scheme

Answer (score 0):

Acrobat JavaScript doesn't have an exportAsXML() method. The best you'll be able to do is use exportAsXFDF() to get an XML representation of the form data and then use an XSLT to transform it into what you need for Excel.